# How do I pipe `file` after `which` in unix-like os

Tags: linux, bash, macos, unix, terminal

```sh
$which python
/usr/bin/python
$file /usr/bin/python
/usr/bin/python: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures ...
```

I tried to use `which python | file` but  it won't work.

Comment: `file $(which python)`

Comment: `file` does not read from stdin. See _man file_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are more than one way to do this. Off the top of my head here are a couple:

1. `file $(which python)`
2. `which python | xargs file`